# Magento is returning “200 OK” status instead of “404 not found”

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I have installed Magento 1.7.0.2.

If I browse to a non-existent URL on my site, I receive a "200 OK" status from the server, despite the URL still being invalid and the 404 page still being presented.

> > culr - I www.shopmami.com//aa
> >     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> >     Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2015 11:27:49 GMT
> >     Server: Apache
> >     X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17

Could you please help me?.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the template Blanco

[root@host.shopmami.com] ~ >> curl -I http://www.almohadaspremama.com/aa

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

I disable the template Blanco and obtain the correct status.
root@host.shopmami.com] ~ >> curl -I http://www.almohadaspremama.com/aa

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found